# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' happened and i have tried everything to fix it

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I've been trying to do this all day I'm making a gui with tkinter but I can't convert the `Entry()` into a int, Ive tried pretty much everything and still cant fix it.

This is the code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root.title("Calculator")
root.configure(bg="#E1E1E1")

# left side labels
l1 = Label(root, text="PD>", bg="#E1E1E1")
l1.grid(row=0, column=0)

l2 = Label(root, text="P1>", bg="#E1E1E1")
l2.grid(row=2, column=0)

l3 = Label(root, text="P2>", bg="#E1E1E1")
l3.grid(row=3, column=0)

l4 = Label(root, text="RD>", bg="#E1E1E1")
l4.grid(row=1, column=0)

# inputs
e = Entry(root, width=25, borderwidth=2, bg="#F0F0F0")
e.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=10)

c = Entry(root, width=25, borderwidth=2, bg="#F0F0F0")
c.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=10)

p1 = Entry(root, width=25, borderwidth=2, bg="#F0F0F0")
p1.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=10)

p2 = Entry(root, width=25, borderwidth=2, bg="#F0F0F0")
p2.grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=10)

l5 = Label(root, text=" ", bg="#E1E1E1", pady=20)
l5.grid(row=4, column=1)

# Descriptions
l6 = Label(root, text="PD = Piston Diameter, Bore;", bg="#E1E1E1")
l6.grid(row=6, column=1, rowspan=1)

l7 = Label(root, text="RD = Rod Diameter, Rod;", bg="#E1E1E1")
l7.grid(row=7, column=1, rowspan=1)

l8 = Label(root, text="P1 = Pressure, Push;", bg="#E1E1E1")
l8.grid(row=8, column=1, rowspan=1)

l9 = Label(root, text="P2 = Pressure, Traction;", bg="#E1E1E1")
l9.grid(row=9, column=1, rowspan=1)

l10 = Label(root, text="mm", bg="#E1E1E1")
l10.grid(row=0, column=2)

l11 = Label(root, text="mm", bg="#E1E1E1")
l11.grid(row=1, column=2)

l12 = Label(root, text="Mpa", bg="#E1E1E1")
l12.grid(row=2, column=2)

l13 = Label(root, text="Mpa", bg="#E1E1E1")
l13.grid(row=3, column=2)

#getting the input 
mp1 = p1.get()
mp2 = p2.get()
me = e.get()
mc = c.get()

mmp1 = int(float(mp1))
mmp2 = int(float(mp2))
mme = int(float(me))
mmc = int(float(mc))

P = ((mmp1 * (mme * mme) * 3.14) / 4) / 1000
R = (mmp2 * ((mme ** 2) - ((mmc ** 2)) * (3.14 / 4)) / 1000

#buttons
def ClickP():
    LP = Label(root, text=(P), bg="#E1E1E1")
    LP.grid(row=5, column=1)


def ClickR():
    LR = Label(root, text=(R), bg="#E1E1E1")
    LR.grid(row=5, column=2)


BP = Button(root, text="P Force", padx=40, pady=20, command=ClickP)
BR = Button(root, text="R Force", padx=40, pady=20, command=ClickR)

BP.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=2)
BR.grid(row=4, column=2, columnspan=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Haven't finished it yet, I was about to work on the buttons tested it and got this error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10
```

Hope I can find the solution soon. I've had similar errors when I change things like:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''
```

or cannot multiply strings. Don't know what else to try.

Comment: For which line you are getting error?

Comment: mmp1 = int(float(mp1)) this one

Comment: And what does it mean `could not convert string to float: ''` when you have `float(mp1)`?

Comment: that happens when i remove the int and try converting it to float

Comment: it couldn't convert it to float because the input string is ```''```

Comment: you can try running it and ull see the problem :(

Comment: yes i got that part but the input here is entry and dont really know to change it from ' '

Comment: since the input is entry dont rly know how to fix it

Comment: its not? what is the correct one?

Comment: Also, `getting the user input` will run once at first time of your code run. I hope this is not the way you want.

Comment: Ann Zen already answered here. Check the solution

Comment: @Knify it's missing a closing `)`.

Comment: yes i just saw that also thank you crackanddie ill check it, also epsi theres a mainloop in the bottom idk if thats what ure reffering to

Comment: `p1, p2, e & c` are all being read by `get` before the GUI is even showing.  Getting the content of the entries needs to be in a callback function, probably called on a button click.  The entries could be initialised to '0' or a conversion function that returns 0 for "" (empty string) created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because the entries you have made are empty at the point where you call the `get()` function on them.

Think of an `Entry` as a textbox where the user can fill in something. By default this textbox will spawn empty, and you can then at a later point in time fill something in it, after the application has started.

This means that when you run

```py
#getting the input 
mp1 = p1.get()
mp2 = p2.get()
me = e.get()
mc = c.get()
```

Python will just fetch the empty fields `''` of each of your entries, which of course cannot be converted to a number, since it is empty.

So how do you solve this? Well that depends mostly on what you are trying to achieve.

#### Option 1

You could define a default value for the entries to hold at creation. That can be done using the `insert()` function. An example (for your first entry) would be something like this

```py
e = Entry(root, width=25, borderwidth=2, bg="#F0F0F0")
e.insert(END, '0')  # Here, I set zero as the default value for your entry
e.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=10)
```

#### Option 2

You define a fallback behaviour when converting to `int`. That could be something like

```
def fallback_value(entry_val):
    if entry_val == '':
        return 0  # Replace with your default value
    else:
        return int(entry_val)

mp1 = fallback_value(p1.get())
mp2 = fallback_value(p2.get())
me = fallback_value(e.get())
mc = fallback_value(c.get())
```

#### Option 3

Make your `get()` calls only triggered after the user filled the entries you've created and pressed a button or something similar. That can be done in a lot of ways, use your imagination.

Comment: i fixed it by adding the 
    mp1 = float(p1.get())
    mp2 = float(p2.get())
    me = float(e.get())
    mc = float(c.get())
under every button functions
thank you for the help

Answer (score 2):

You can use this `for` loop too see where the problem(s) is/are happening:

```
mp1 = p1.get()
mp2 = p2.get()
me = e.get()
mc = c.get()

lst = [mp1, mp2, me, mc]
for m in lst:
    try:
        m = int(float(m))
    except:
        print(f"Can't convert {m} into a float.")
```

The above loop will tell you which of the four strings cannot be converted to a float.

Note: The `except` statement used above will blindly take any error and proceed to print. If you only want it to print when the `ValueError` happens, do this instead:

```
for m in lst:
    try:
        m = int(float(m))
    except ValueError:
        print(f"Can't convert {m} into a float.")
```

Comment: Can't convert  into a float. This is what it said 4 times im guessing non of them can convert

Comment: @xKnify That means that every element in the list are empty strings, `''`.

Comment: yeah since it opens a gui where u have to type the inputs. How can i fix it? Do you know a way

Comment: @xKnify You mean `lst = [mp1, mp2, me, mc]` into `lst = [input(), input(), input(), input()]`?

Comment: the tkinters entry is supposed to open a gui where you type inside the entry box then the .get command takes the info from that box but since theres a error the gui doesnt open so theres no value to the input strings. Idk im probably doing something wrong. Kinda new to python

Comment: if u run half of the program right before the .get commands u can see the gui

Comment: @xKnify You can use an `input("Press ENTER when you're done >>> ")` statement somewhere in your code to pause the program while the user inputs the values into the entry box.